# Wso2 esb AWS SQS Mediator messageAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, amazon-sqs, api-manager, wso2-esb

i've problem with Amazon SQS Mediator in wso2 ESB.

How can I sendMessage with messageAttributes ?

I've tried with

```
<attributes>Name=andrea&amp;Type=String&amp;Value=234</attributes>
```

and with

```
<messageAttributes>Name=andrea&amp;Type=String&amp;Value=234</messageAttributes>
```

but not work

Thanks very much for help

Answer (score 0):

The attributes specification must follow an exact format suggested by AWS.
[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSMessageAttributes.html#sqs-attrib-api) you can find something similar, which in your case becomes:

```
<messageAttributes>MessageAttribute.1.Name=andrea&amp;MessageAttribute.1.Value.StringValue=234&amp;MessageAttribute.1.Value.DataType=String</messageAttributes>
```

If you want to add a new attribute you just have to increase the number next to `MessageAttribute`.